# Trigonometry - Calculate an angle based on a fixed central point

Tags: actionscript-3, trigonometry

I have a 1000x1000 grid with a fixed point (p1) in the centre and a variable point (p2). How can I calculate, in degrees, the angle indicated in red? The vertical blue line will always be fixed as 0 degrees.

[image: Diagram]

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this a programming question, or a math question?

Comment: I'm sorry, I should have been clearer - it's a programming question (now solved). For the benefit of anyone searching, I am creating a panorama using the Sky Box class of Away 3D, using Actionscript 3.0. The camera is a hovercontroller which is fixed permanently in the centre of the cube (p1). I needed to rotate the camera to look at particular objects (eg p2) based on supplied coordinates. After a lot of fiddling, I found that the following works: `var degrees:Number = ( -( -180 + (Math.atan2(x, y) * 180 / Math.PI)));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`arctan(p2.y/p2.x) + 90` works for the upper-left quadrant.  Depending on how you want to calculate the other quadrants you can either use the same formula or use the inverse as `abs(result - 180)`

Comment: Many thanks. I finally got it working how I wanted using the following (as3): `var degrees:Number = ( -( -180 + (Math.atan2(x, y) * 180 / Math.PI)));`  This can probably inefficient but for now I am just grateful that it works

Answer (score 2):

A few hints to guide you in understanding why the solutions you've seen/will see work...

Let p2 be sitting in the position (x,y) on your grid; What is the projection of p2 onto the x axis, or p2 onto the y axis?

Where is p1 located?

How do you determine the distance between two points on a coordinate axis?

What would pythagoras say the length of the line connecting p1 and p2 is?

What trigonometric facts do you know of that relate the sides of a triangle to an angle?

If we know cos(x) = a, then x = ...?

Comment: Thank you HexedAgain, I should have been more attentive in school.

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate the angle with the following formula:

```
if(x>0)
    angle = cos^-1(y/(sqrt(x^2+y^2))
else 
    angle = 180 + cos^-1(y/(sqrt(x^2+y^2))
```

where `x` is the horizontal distance between `p1` and `p2` and `y` is the vertical.